# CD4017 Decade Counter Based LED Flasher Question

Tags: led, 555, cd4017

I am creating a simple LED Flasher with NE555 and CD4017. I am actually dividing the pulse frequency of NE555 by five. Because I have merged each pair of the output pins to finally get 5 outputs.

I have attached 4 pieces of 3V LEDs (draws approx 200mA current each) in Series to each of the 5 outputs.

I couldn't find any error in the circuit. But when I test the circuit, I measure only 3V-5V at the five output pins. As a result the LEDs do not glow. What could be wrong in the circuit? My question is specifically around the values of resistors. Are they too high to allow sufficient current?

The circuit diagram (partial, showing only 1 of the 5 outputs) is given below.

[image]

Comment: Your schematic doesn't show power or ground for the 4017.  Are they connected but not shown in the diagram?

Comment: That also isn't the circuit you are using.  Your description sounds strange.

Comment: @JRE Yes, Power (Pin 16) and Ground (pin 8,13,15) of CD4017 are connected. I just drawn the diagram quickly so omitted them. For Power pin, I have directly connected Pin 16 to 12V Vcc, no resistor used.
For the outputs I have shown the first output only from Pin 3 and 2 (Q0 and Q1 respectively).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't connect 2 outputs together.  When 1 output is high, the other will be pulling it low.  This will explain why you are getting a low voltage on the outputs.  You could use 2 diodes to connect 2 outputs together, but you will then need a pull down resistor on the transistor base.

i would have thought you would be better just using the first 5 outputs and then connecting the 6th to the reset pin.

Comment: Ah! That's what I suspected. Thanks for confirming. Yes, I can use only first 5 pins to get the same output effect, probably a little larger capacitor with NE555 would increase the LED 'on' time in this new config. If you could give an idea on how much value for the pull down resistor will be suitable for this circuit... Do I still need the base current limiting resistor between the diodes and the BC547?

Comment: If you are only going to use 5 of the outputs and you are not joining them together with diodes, then you wont need the pull down resistor.  If you are using the diodes, I would suggest 22K for the pull down.  Yes you will need the current limiting resistor.  100R seems too low, maybe 1K.

Answer (score 2):

Four 3 volt LEDs connected in series will drop 12 volts.  Since you have a 12 volt supply, that doesn't leave any room for a current limiting resistor, or your transistor switching circuit.  If you need to run from12 volts, you should only have three LEDs in series.

200 mA through the 100 Ohm emitter resistor will drop 20 volts, so your circuit can't possibly provide 200 mA to the LEDs, regardless of the number of LEDs you use.

Comment: Thanks for responding. While redesigning the circuit I would make sure to put only 3 series LEDs per set. But, 3v-5v output is probably because of the problem identified by HandyHowie. Because I already tried with 3 LEDs as well with no success.